# Estimating odds of random sequence recurring -- very big numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I have two related questions. I'm trying to calculate the odds that at least one sequence of 30 characters (a "30-mer") will recur within a random sequence of one billion characters, drawn from an alphabet of four.

This is how I'm thinking about it:

- There are $10^9 - 29$ positions a sequence can begin in. Let's just call it $10^9$
- There are thus $\binom{10^9}{2}$ chances to make a match
- Given one 30-mer, the odds that another matches are $1 / 4^{30}$, which I'll approximate as $1 / 10^{18}$.
- So, the odds of NEVER getting a single match are about
  $$\left[\frac{10^{18}-1}{10^{18}}\right]^\binom{10^9}{2}
       = \left(1-10^{-18}\right)^\binom{10^9}{2}
     $$

I have two questions:

1. Am I doing it right?
2. How in the world do I estimate what that expression comes out to, as it's way too big to evaluate.

I'll add that empirically, I know that the odds are very low, but if you drop to 25-mers, you expect some matches (I wrote a script to test).

Comment: @gt6989b Thanks for the LaTex editing kind stranger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic approach is correct.  In your third bullet, the chance of a match with a specific sequence is $1/4^{30}\approx 1/10^{18}$  Note that ${10^9 \choose 2}=5\cdot 10^{17}$ (I'll use $5E17$ to keep it in one line), so we want to evaluate $\left(1-10^{-18}\right)^{5E17}$

We can evaluate this using logs: $\log\left(1-10^{-18}\right)^{5E17}=5E17\log\left(1-10^{-18}\right)\approx -5E17 \cdot 1E-18=-0.5$ With $e^{-0.5}\approx 0.61$, the chances are about $1$ in $3$ of a match.  We used the approximation $\log (1+x)\approx x$ for $x \ll 1$  I think with $25$ you should (almost) always get a match.

The [Wikipedia article on the generalized birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox#The_generalized_birthday_problem) makes less approximations because the numbers are not so large.  In your case you have to ignore the overlapping of the runs of 30, but that doesn't make any difference to speak of.

Comment: Thanks. It was that approximation I needed. (Well, that and the reminder to use logs :).

Answer (score 1):

There are about ${{10^9}\choose{2}}\approx 5\times 10^{17}$ ways to choose which two intervals match.  For each such pair of intervals, the probability of a match is $4^{-30}=2^{-60}\approx 10^{-18}$.  So the probability of no match is about
$$
\left(1-10^{-18}\right)^{5\times 10^{17}}\approx\exp\left(-\frac{5\times 10^{17}}{10^{18}}\right)=e^{-1/2}\approx 0.6.
$$

Comment: This is also right.